# Maximum CPU time limit is inconsistent between orgs

Tags: governorlimits, cpulimit

I work on 3 different orgs. Today while going through a log, I noticed that one org has **Maximum CPU time limit of 42000** milliseconds in all synchronous calls. As per [governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm)  the limits are 10,000 ms and 60,000 ms for synchronous and asynchronous calls respectively. I'm wondering where this 42,000 ms came from. The other two orgs have 10,000 ms limit.

**Org 1 (NA13):**

[image]

**Org 2 (NA33):**

[image]

**Org 3 (NA48):**

[image]

All the other limits are same between all the orgs. Has any one seen this before? I couldn't understand the logic behind this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When salesforce rolled out CPU limits in the org which already had lot of code  ,to avoid breaking of code in existing orgs,they analyzed each org and figured the maximum CPU time taken by code .Seems like  your original org that was there before CPU limits was rolled and hence you are seeing increased limit as that would have a class which needed CPU limit of 4X .

You should figure the class which is taking 4X limit in that org and try and reduce the same .

Comment: Woah that's crazy. Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: That org was created in mid 2011. I think the CPU time limits were in place by then.

Comment: @AvinashN - I believe CPU limits were introduced in winter 14 http://advancedapex.com/2013/08/22/goodbye-script-limits/

Comment: @AdrianLarson If you dig into webinars and blog posts that happened that time ,you will find that .Every org was analyzed before rolling this feature

Comment: @AvinashN CPU limits came in 2013 .Thanks

Comment: I have no idea where to find those webinars and don't really have the time to listen through them. I believe you, but I'd be much more likely to vote this answer up if you had some proof.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Check this post from Andy and check all the comments .http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18244/how-does-sf-calculate-the-cpu-time/18246#18246 .

Comment: Also read the blog that Eric shared and specially section "But I Have Fear And Doubt!" .You will get an idea :) .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, I couldn't find the text "But I Have Fear And Doubt!" in the blog shared by Eric. Could you please throw a screenshot at me?

Comment: Sorry its this blog https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/09/script-limits-begone.html