# How to debug the error: 'Apex CPU time limit exceeded'

Tags: apex, governorlimits, cpulimit

The trigger written in my salesforce org is hitting the apex cpu time limit . Hence I am trying to optimize apex code and reducing the workflow updates. But below log is confusing me about the apex governor limits:

```
> 16:11:02.820 |CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
16:11:02.820 |LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 2 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 203 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 2 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 201 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 19336 out of 10000 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10
16:11:02.820 (91820619113)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END
```

Can anyone help me understand why does it show

> Maximum CPU time: 19336 out of 10000 * CLOSE TO LIMIT

As salesforce governor limit for CPU time is 10000ms, it should throw error right after 10000ms. Am I missing something here? I am not able to see the actual consumption of CPU time in the logs,as the debug log size is big and salesforce is supressing the system.debugs I have put in the code. Can anyone suggest if there is any effective way to debug the apex CPU limit consumption?

Comment: Check this post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18244/how-does-sf-calculate-the-cpu-time   . Also, upload your log file to this Heroku application and check where its consuming more time: https://apextimeline.herokuapp.com

Comment: developer console profiler can be helpful to see where the time is going

Comment: please post your code